# Sum of List<Integer, Integer> elements in Java

Tags: java, search, arraylist

I have an `ArrayList` which contain some `Integer values` as `Pairs`. I want to sum the `right` elements of the List where the left element is the same.

For example, the input arrayList will contain:

```
final List<Pair<Integer, Integer>> a = new ArrayList<>();
a.add(new Pair<>(1, 1));
a.add(new Pair<>(2, 1));
a.add(new Pair<>(2, 3));
```

`New ArrayList should contain:`

As seen below:

(common left value, sum of all the right values where left value is the same)

```
1, 1
2, 4
```

Code I have written that doesn't return valid values:

```
for (int i=0; i< a.size(); i++){


        //need help here
}
```

EDIT: I want duplicate pairs so a HashMap won't work.

Sorry for the edits.

Comment: Can you use a map instead of a list of pairs for the result?

Comment: You could use a `HashMap<Integer, Integer>` and sum values up for the keys.

Comment: He probably wants repeat key value pairs.

Comment: I want duplicate key value pairs so hashmap wont work

Comment: The question doesn't state anything about those duplicate key value pairs in the result. In fact the provided description and example suggest that the result should not contain duplicates. ("common left value, sum of all the right values where left value is the same" - having duplicates in the result would not match that requirement)

Comment: Regarding the edit: please be specific on _where_ you need those duplicates. If it's the input lists then it doesn't relate to using a map. It it's the result list then please specify _where those duplicates would come from_.

Comment: So would `1,2`, `2,8`, `2,8`, `1,2`, `2,8`, `2,8` be the solution? It'll take you two more little loops :D

Comment: Sorry about that. I have updated the question for simplicity. Please pardon me for so many edits, I am a new user. Thank you.

Comment: The duplicate handling is still not clear. If your result contained `(3,10)` and `(3,10)`, shouldn't that have been combined to `(3,20)` right from the beginning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need some hacked `HashMap`, which will sum values instead of replacing them:

```
class SummingMap extends HashMap<Integer, Integer> {
    @Override
    public Integer put(Integer key, Integer value) {
        Integer oldResult = get(key);
        return super.put(key, value + (oldResult == null ? 0 : oldResult));
    }
}
```

If you want your entries to be sorted by key, you should use some kind of `SortedMap`, for example, `TreeMap`:

```
class SummingMap extends TreeMap<Integer, Integer> {
   ... // the same code as above
```

Comment: @cp101020304 Okay, and now?

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. How would you sort this based on keys and then values?

Comment: @cp101020304 if the keys are unique (and they are in any `Map`), then you shouldn't be aware of sorting by values. So, all you need is some king of `SortedMap`, which will by default sort elements by keys. I'll update answer to reflect this change.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you only add two elements in your loops which works for 1 but not for 2. Instead, you should use a map with the key being the first number (1 or  2 in your case) and the value being the sum.

Then you loop over both lists independently, get the current value for the left number, add the right number to it and put the result back into the map. If there's no value yet, you'd assume 0.

Something like this:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> sums = new HashMap<>();

for( Pair<> p : a ) {
  Integer sum = sums.get(p.left);
  if( sum == null ) {
    sums.put( p.left, p.right ); //nothing there yet, so just add the first value
  } else {
    sums.put( p.left, sum + p.right ); //add to the existing sum
  }
}

//do the same for b
```

Finally iterate over the map and build your new list of pairs as needed.

In case you need to get the original pairs as well, create a container object to be used as the value which contains the sum as well as a list of the pairs that contributed to that sum. I'll leave the code as an exercise for you.

Comment: @cp101020304 you want them in the result? If so, you should definitely expand your question. If they can just be in the input lists, then this is possible.

Answer (score 1):

This is untested code but should give you an idea

```
HashMap<Integer, Integer> result = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
List<Pair<Integer, Integer>> list = new ArrayList<Pair<Integer, Integer>>();

for (Pair p : a)
  if (result.containsValue(p.left)) 
    result.put(p.left, p.right +result.get(p.left)); // add if existing
  else
    result.put(p.left, p.right);                     // assign if not existing 

for (Pair p : b)
  if (result.containsValue(p.left)) 
    result.put(p.left, p.right +result.get(p.left));
  else
    result.put(p.left, p.right);
```

***p.s.*** (as per comment): add new pairs to list:

```
for (Pair p : a)
  list.add(new Pair(p.left, result.get(p.left)));

for (Pair p : b)
  list.add(new Pair(p.left, result.get(p.left)));
```

Answer (score 1):

Using org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap:

```
List<Pair<Integer, Integer>> result = new ArrayList<>();

a.addAll(b); //now there is only one list

//key -> Integer, value -> List<Integer>
MultiValueMap<Integer, Integer> values = new LinkedMultiValueMap<Integer, Integer>();

for (Pair p : a) 
    values.add(p.left, p.right);

for (Integer key : values.keySet()) {
    Integer sum = 0;
    for (Integer right : values.get(key))
        sum += right;
    result.add(new Pair(key, sum));
}
```

Comment: Hi, would there be an alternative to `MultiValueMap`?

Comment: Internally, this data structure is a `Map<T, List<T>>` implemented by Spring developers. `add(key, value)` method append `value` to `data[key]` (that is a List). You don't have to care about `List` initialization or that stuff. I recommend you to use it.

Comment: @cp101020304 As an alternative you could use Google Guava's Multimap which comes in different flavors. But besides being from a different library the concept is the same.